# Using zip to append value from list to another

Tags: python, list, append

I have the following two lists

```
list_1
[('Person A', [(6, "example.com/h"), (1, "example.com/xqz"), (7, "example.com/abc"), (9, "example.com/efg")]), 
('Person B', [(4, "example.com/a"), (5, "example.com/rrr"), (1, "example.com/ddd"), (4, "example.com/nnn")]),
('Person C', [(3, "example.com/g"), (1, "example.com/qqq"), (7, "example.com/fff"), (3, "example.com/vvv")])]

list_2
['2', '6', '2', '23', '2', '6', '9', '25', '2', '5', '7', '19']
```

list_1 contains data counts belong to a person and the hyperlinks where the data is coming from.
list_2 includes additional numbers that I'd like to append in list_1 respectively

The desire outcome is something like this in dict format:

```
{'Person A': [((6, "example.com/h"), '2'), ((1, "example.com/xqz"), '6'), ((7, "example.com/abc"), '2'), ((9, "example.com/efg"), '23')], 
'Person B': [((4, "example.com/a"), '2'), ((5, "example.com/rrr"), '6'), ((1, "example.com/ddd"), '9'), ((4, "example.com/nnn"), '25')],
'Person C': [((3, "example.com/g"), '2'), ((1, "example.com/qqq"), '5'), ((7, "example.com/fff"), '7'), ((3, "example.com/vvv"), '19')]}
```

My original thought is simply using zip to get the outcome I want but I'm getting incorrect result:

```
{'Person A': [((6, "example.com/h"), '2'), ((1, "example.com/xqz"), '6'), ((7, "example.com/abc"), '2'), ((9, "example.com/efg"), '23')], 
'Person B': [((4, "example.com/a"), '2'), ((5, "example.com/rrr"), '6'), ((1, "example.com/ddd"), '2'), ((4, "example.com/nnn"), '23')],
'Person C': [((3, "example.com/g"), '2'), ((1, "example.com/qqq"), '6'), ((7, "example.com/fff"), '2'), ((3, "https://xxx./vvv"), '23')]}
```

```
sample_dict = dict()

for i in list_1:
      result = list(zip(i[1], list_2))
      sample_dict[i[0]] = result

print(sample_dict)
```

Trying to understand where I did wrong and what might be other good approaches to do this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where is that first list coming from? Can you share more of your code? A dict is a good idea, but I would create it far earlier in your program. Also, just trying to print the two lists is giving me a syntax error.

Comment: On top of the code, some details on the general format of your data could be useful. There are multiple possible solutions here, and which one is the best depends on that data.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile - thanks, the first list is coming from two different data points. I first combine them in a dict format but I need to sort them in a specific order where Person A will always need to be the first and so on. So I convert to list.

Regarding the syntax error, what error did you see? I just tried the above lists I shared, everything works fine. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Can you expand on what those 2 sources are? Is the number of count and hyperlink pairs the same for each Person?

Comment: I got an error because, drumroll please........ my variable name accidentally contained a space!

Comment: @AlexanderCécile - one data source is coming from ldap directory. The main task is to sum up the total data counts and display the numbers under the top level person.

For example: 
Person A may have a few direct reports:
A.1, A.2, A.3

I sum up the total data counts and display the number under A. At the same time, I create a dynamic URL which the platform can actually embed the search in the URL. So far, everything looks good but I want to add additional numbers from a list and append to each individual sublist as I mentioned above.

Comment: The number/url pairs correspond to a direct report? The count of direct reports can vary, right?

Comment: Yes, yes, this is correct :)

Comment: Hmm, that’s always annoying. Where is the data going, once this is done?

Comment: An email will be generated and included the results

Comment: For each Person?

Comment: Yes, the email will include all the results for each person that I include in the offline directory file. This is a very complicated design due to the very legacy workflow that I'm trying to automate :(

Comment: Yeah, it sounds a bit awkward. A dictionary or class may be your best bet. Maybe namedtuples for the number, url, other number elements?

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit awkward. I'm considering to use dict as I feel this is the easiest way in my opinion. @Prince Francis just provided an approach and I see where I missed. Thanks for chatting

Comment: Dict + namedtuples is probably the easiest way of doing this without it becoming a complete mess, yeah.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using dictionary comprehension with `iter` beforehand:

```
it = iter(list_2)
print({k:[(i, next(it)) for i in v] for k, v in list_1})
```

Output:

```
{'Person A': [((6, 'example.com/h'), '2'), ((1, 'example.com/xqz'), '6'), ((7, 'example.com/abc'), '2'), ((9, 'example.com/efg'), '23')], 'Person B': [((4, 'example.com/a'), '2'), ((5, 'example.com/rrr'), '6'), ((1, 'example.com/ddd'), '9'), ((4, 'example.com/nnn'), '25')], 'Person C': [((3, 'example.com/g'), '2'), ((1, 'example.com/qqq'), '5'), ((7, 'example.com/fff'), '7'), ((3, 'example.com/vvv'), '19')]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are always passing `list_2` for `zip`. So in each loop it will take first 4 elements to `zip`.
Need to remove already ziped elements from list_2 for next iterations.
You could try as follows

```
sample_dict = dict()

for i in list_1:
      result = [c for c in zip(i[1], list_2)]
      sample_dict[i[0]] = result
      list_2 = list_2[len(i[1]):]
sample_dict
```

It gives you the following output.

```
{'Person A': [((6, 'example.com/h'), '2'),
  ((1, 'example.com/xqz'), '6'),
  ((7, 'example.com/abc'), '2'),
  ((9, 'example.com/efg'), '23')],
 'Person B': [((4, 'example.com/a'), '2'),
  ((5, 'example.com/rrr'), '6'),
  ((1, 'example.com/ddd'), '9'),
  ((4, 'example.com/nnn'), '25')],
 'Person C': [((3, 'example.com/g'), '2'),
  ((1, 'example.com/qqq'), '5'),
  ((7, 'example.com/fff'), '7'),
  ((3, 'example.com/vvv'), '19')]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the `list2` into groups of 4 like this

```
>>> updates = [list2[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(list2),4)]
>>> updates
[['2', '6', '2', '23'], ['2', '6', '9', '25'], ['2', '5', '7', '19']]
```

and then create a `dict` like this

```
>>> output = {}
>>> for a,b in zip(list1, updates):        )])
...     output[a[0]] = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(a[1],b)]
...

>>> output
{'Person A': [((6, 'example.com/h'), '2'),
              ((1, 'example.com/xqz'), '6'), 
              ((7,'example.com/abc'), '2'),
              ((9, 'example.com/efg'), '23')],
 'Person B': [((4, 'example.com/a'), '2'), 
              ((5, 'example.com/rrr'), '6'),
              ((1, 'example.com/ddd'), '9'),
              ((4, 'example.com/nnn'), '25')],
 'Person C': [((3, 'example.com/g'), '2'),
              ((1, 'example.com/qqq'), '5'), 
              ((7, 'example.com/fff'), '7'),
              ((3, 'example.com/vvv'), '19')]}
```